# Change background image of image button in android?

Tags: android, xml, image

There is an image background of imageButton.
It has an default image background at the time of un-select.
When the imageButton is click its background image changes and is select.
Now I need is when user click again on ImageButton it background image should be change as was at time unselect time default image.

Here is my Activity image button code :-

```
    img1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    //img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //start();
                //img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.badmiton_blur);
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);

        }
    });
```

Here is my xml code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
   android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/badmintion140"
    />
<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/badmiton_blur"
    />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one boolean varialbe

```
boolean isClicked;
```

and change your code like this.

```
boolean isClicked;
img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
            isClicked=!isClicked;
            if (isClicked) {
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
            }else {
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaut);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @thanks.. There are 5 different image Button if I use this on click of any 1 imagebutton the background of all imagebutton will be change

Comment: @madhavan as like above change all imagesButton images in onclick method

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
 boolean defaultImage=true;


img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isClicked) {
            defaultImage=false;
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }
         else
         {
           defaultImage=true;
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaut);
        }
    }
});
```